# Drupal 7, how to add text to the user profile page

Tags: drupal-7

I need to add a paragraph of text near the top of the user profile page found at /user, this is page you are initially taken to after login.

I'm not fluent with Drupal, and I can't find any answers online.

Could any advise how I can add text to the user profile page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also add a block to the "content area" to be shown below the user profile (restricted to user/* pages). In the block you an use short PHP snippets.

Answer (score 0):

In a custom Drupal module you could use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.5.x), this will let you change the user profile form, where you could attach a **div** element that will hold the paragraph text you wish to insert to the page. You will also give **weight** to your div, so that it is displayed on top of the form.

Here is a code snippet:

```
function custommodulename_form_user_profile_form_alter() {

    $description_html = '<div>Lorem ipsum...</div>';

    $form['description'] = array(
        '#markup' => $description_html,
        '#weight' => -10,
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the form I want to change, it's the page at /user that displays the users information after they have logged in.